# How can I change row's active state value in v-data-table?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, v-data-table

I want to set the "active" row to values "active" or "not active" wheter the value is true or false. With my code here, I always get "not active" value (I've tested the condition both with true or false, so my guess is I'm not getting any value in condition). By the way, I can't use v-for in data table if that's relevant. Thanks

```
<v-data-table :items="locations" :headers="headers" class="elevation-1">

  <template slot="item" slot-scope="row">
    <tr>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ row.item.code }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ row.item.name }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ row.item.descr }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ row.item.dateFrom }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ row.item.dateTo }}</td>
      <td :class="row.item.active === true ? row.item.active='active' : row.item.active='not active'" class="text-xs-right">{{ row.item.active }}</td>
    </tr>
  </template>

</v-data-table>
```

Comment: You'll probably want to show the code that sets the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the value to `row.item.active` so the active variable contains `'active'` or `'not-active'` instead of `true` or `false` that is why you always get `'not-active'` since the `row.item.active === true` always resolves to `false`

```
<td :class="(row.item.active === true ? 'active' : 'not-active') + ' text-xs-right'">{{ row.item.active }}</td>
```

---

**Updated Answer**

```
<td class="text-xs-right">{{ row.item.active ? 'active' : 'not active' }}</td>
```

Comment: I've tried your way first, and now again, but if I put it like that it just shows "true" or "false" values in that row.

Comment: Lol, I feel ashamed now that I didn't think of this... Banging my head whole day, and the answer is easy as this. Thank you man so much.